# Cut Out Data between specific pipe SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hope Someone can help my fried brain here....

I want to know if it would be possible to Cut out a string between a specific '|' pipe from my text file.

I need to extract certain words from a pipe delimited file in order to use further down the line in my query which will always be in a specific location (Not in terms of length of characters but after a specific pipe).

For instance
right at the end of my string I find data like this  :

```
|04-MAY-2017 14:40:22|INSERT|No|N|N
```

Bare in mind that there are 118 of these pipes and these are right at the end of it

My Expected output from there would be to extract and display 'INSERT'or whatever is within those two pipes.

I need to use this script to determine which lines of data to delete from my list before i bring them in and doing the piping. Because i need to use this logic to decide what to do with the line of data. ( I delete it if theres anything else than 'UPDATE' or 'INSERT' else i pass them to an update or insert script)

I count the pipes like this :

```
select len(lineDAta) - len(replace(lineData, '|', '')) from [MyTable]
```

So now I know that I need to cut out the data between pipe 115 and pipe 116. But thats where my skills stopped. How do you retrieve data between two pipes at variable character length location but always after pipe 115?

So it might be that the word ''INSERT' is at length 2000 and the next line 3000 but it will always be after 115 |'s

Thanks

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS which you are using.

Comment: If your text file is pipe delimited then why not just use a method which allows for the use of the pipes as delimiters in your query? You can do a simple import and specify a pipe delimiter and then you will have a table with all of your INSERT values in a single column instead of parsing. Definitely an XY problem here. It's literally the example on the meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: add your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I have edited accordingly